# Add node to end of a list in C

Tags: c, struct, nodes

I'm writing a little program in C to read in a file and put what it contains in a linked list. I am able to create the list with the first element, but everytime I add an element, it overwrite what it added before.

Here's my code so far :

```
<pre> 
struct test_struct
{
char* valeur;
char** tableau;
struct test_struct *next;
};
FILE* ouvrirFichier(char* fichier);
struct test_struct* create_list(char* ligne);
struct test_struct* add_to_list(char* ligne);
void print_list();
struct test_struct *head = NULL;
struct test_struct *curr = NULL;
//struct test_struct *ptr = NULL;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
//int i = 0, ret = 0;
struct test_struct *ptr = NULL;
FILE* fichier = NULL;
char ligne[121] = {0};
fichier = ouvrirFichier(argv[1]);
while(fgets(ligne, 121, fichier))
{
    ptr = add_to_list(ligne);
    printf("%sn", courant->valeur);
    printf("%sn", ptr -> valeur);
}
print_list();
return 0;
}
struct test_struct* create_list(char* ligne)
{
//printf("n creating list with headnode as [%d]n",val);
struct test_struct *ptr = (struct test_struct*)malloc(sizeof(struct     test_struct));
char* info[121] = {0};
char separateurs[] = "[]";
int j = 0;
int k = 0;
char* element;
if(NULL == ptr)
{
    printf("n Node creation failed n");
    return NULL;
}
for (element = strtok(ligne, separateurs); element; element = strtok(NULL, separateurs))
{
    if (strcmp(element, " ") != 0 && strcmp(element, "n") != 0)
    {
        info[j] = element;
        //printf("%sn", info[j]);
        //info[j] = element;
        j++;
    }
}
k = j;
ptr-> valeur = info[0];
ptr -> tableau = malloc(k);
printf("%s234n", ptr -> valeur);
for (j = 1; j < k; j++)
{
    ptr -> tableau[j - 1] = malloc(strlen(info[j]));
    ptr -> tableau[j - 1] = info[j];
    //printf("%s ", tete -> tableau[j - 1]);
}
ptr->next = NULL;
head = curr = ptr;
return ptr;
}
FILE* ouvrirFichier(char* entree)
{
FILE* fichier = NULL;
fichier = fopen(entree, "r");
if (fichier == NULL) // Le fichier n'a pu être ouvert
{
    perror("Erreur d'ouverture du fichier d'entrée ");
    exit(1);
}
return fichier;
}
struct test_struct* add_to_list(char* ligne)
{
int j = 0;
int k = 0;
//char ligne[121] = {0};
char* info[121] = {0};
char* element;
char separateurs[] = "[]";
if(NULL == head)
{
    return (create_list(ligne));
}
//if(add_to_end)
//printf("n Adding node to end of list with value [%d]n",val);
//else
//printf("n Adding node to beginning of list with value [%d]n",val);
struct test_struct *ptr = (struct test_struct*)malloc(sizeof(struct test_struct));
if(NULL == ptr)
{
    printf("n Node creation failed n");
    return NULL;
}
for (element = strtok(ligne, separateurs); element; element = strtok(NULL, separateurs))
{
    if (strcmp(element, " ") != 0 && strcmp(element, "n") != 0)
    {
        info[j] = element;
        //printf("%sn", info[j]);
        info[j] = element;
        j++;
    }
}
k = j;
ptr-> valeur = info[0];
ptr -> tableau = malloc(k);
printf("%s123n", ptr -> valeur);
for (j = 1; j < k; j++)
{
    ptr -> tableau[j - 1] = malloc(strlen(info[j]));
    ptr -> tableau[j - 1] = info[j];
}
ptr->next = NULL;
return ptr;
}</pre>
```

The content in the file look like this : ab [c] [d].

Thanks

Comment: Please format your code if you want any help.

Comment: Atleast use proper format and english name please.

Answer (score 1):

When you set value in `ptr-> valeur` you should allocate new memory rather than just storing a pointer in add and create list functions.

So change

```
ptr-> valeur = info[0];
```

to

```
ptr-> valeur = strdup(info[0]);
```

Also, in `add_to_list()` function you set `ptr` for the node to add in the list but you never add it into the list. If you want to add it at the end, traverse it to the end and then add the `ptr` node there.